# Oracle AQ's requeue

Tags: oracle, plsql, advanced-queuing

I am trying to write universal pl/sql to (re)enqueue message already enqueued (present in queue table in whatever state).

It works fine when dequeue is enabled on the queue so I can dequeue first in browse mode in order to populate `DBMS_AQ.message_properties_t` and load from existing message. But how can I fetch those when dequeue is disabled?

```
  DBMS_AQ.enqueue(
       queue_name          => fine,
       enqueue_options     => fine,
       message_properties  => how from existing message,
       payload             => how from existing message 
                                     (probably can select, not big deal),
       msgid               => fine);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a great example of how to do this on Oracle's site:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/apexampl.htm

Basically you can "dequeue" in a non destructive fashion (IE dequeue for purposes of browsing).  Because you aren't dequeuing though, the message still stay in place.

Comment: Hello Alan, I am aware of the DBMS_AQ.BROWSE mode for dequeue, but when the dequeue is disabled on queue it thows an error even in browse mode.

Answer (score 1):

You **HAVE** to enable DEQUEUING in order to get a message, no matter if in **browse** or **remove** mode:

```
begin
   sys.dbms_aqadm.start_queue('[QUEUE_NAME]', true, true);
end;
/
```